# CentOS7でSquid3.5を使用しています。4.10にアップグレードしたい場合ってどのようにしたらいいでしょうか。

Tags: linux, centos, yum, squid

CentOS7でSquid3.5を使用しています。
バージョンを4.10にアップグレードしたい場合ってどのようにしたらいいでしょうか。
もしご存知の方がいらっしゃったら教えていただけると助かります

```
[root@localhost]# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:centos:centos:7"
HOME_URL="https://www.centos.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.centos.org/"

CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT="CentOS-7"
CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION="7"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="centos"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7"

[root@localhost]# squid -v
Squid Cache: Version 3.5.20
Service Name: squid
```

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7 のディストリビューションとしてサポートしている Squid パッケージは **v3.5** までのようです。
(CentOS 8 であれば Squid-v4.0.x がパッケージとして見つかりました)

選択肢としては…

- Squid 公式サイトのドキュメントを見ると、CentOS 7 向けの Squid-4.x パッケージがコミュニティリポジトリでいくつか公開されていますが、こちらは **v4.1-5** まででした。

  [SquidFaq/BinaryPackages - Squid Web Proxy Wiki](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/BinaryPackages#KnowledgeBase.2FCentOS.Squid-4_release)
- どうしても **v4.10** 以降が必要、というのであればソースコードからコンパイルしてインストールする形になると思います。

  [Download | squid : Optimising Web Delivery](http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/v4/)